# Dual boot with Windows + Ubuntu in the same HD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm trying to dual boot Windows + Ubuntu using the same HD. However, I've tried to make a partition to install the Linux distribution and unfortunately it has only 16GB of space.

I know that I can use this available space to install Ubuntu, but I'm not sure if its sufficient given my purpose (Code in C, use RStudio, and maybe create some latex documents).

So, I have some questions:

1. Can I install Ubuntu programs outside its partition?
2. Given that Ubuntu will be allocated at the end of the HD (I guess), should I have to worry about slow performance of the OS?

Comment: Your space seems insufficient for what you want to do. No, a beginner cannot install applications elsewhere. Even experts avoid haywiring like that. Advice: Free up enough (not minimal) space for your project on your HDD before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345107/how-to-save-applications-for-re-install-or-upgrade/345115#345115) for why you cannot install Ubuntu programs outside its partition.

Comment: If shrinking/changing a Windows partition, do it with Window's tools, not Ubuntu/Linux.  If Windows partition is too filled to shrink enough, can install Ubuntu on an external drive.  Ubuntu does not care what drive it is on.  Might be able to install Ubuntu in 16GBs, but will find you have no space left to do anything.  I prefer more than 50GBs at least.

Comment: The amount you can shrink Windows can be limited by immovable files if they happen to be in the area of the drive you are trying to release. There are a number of immovable files but if the function they support is turned off temporarily they are no longer a problem.  When you turn the function back on they are recreated in a different place within the Windows partition. This is a guide https://techsprobe.com/you-cannot-shrink-a-volume-beyond-the-point-where-fix/ If you have space on a Windows partition but cannot release it this is the solution

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I'm afraid of messing with these immovable files because of my lack of experience. I'm also thinking about buying a SSD of 240GB and dividing it into two partitions; one for windows (180 GB) and another for Ubuntu (60GB). My primary idea was to install Ubuntu in my HD (size of 1tb) and leave SSD for Windows, but seems like GRUB couldn't work properly with two different memory compartments. What should I do? I'm very confused.